# Angular Component passed into an iframe's 'srcdoc' property renders outside of the iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I'm recreating a component I built for demonstrating responsiveness and am trying to simplify it.  The old version can be viewed [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdlkej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and the way I'm trying to simplify it is by passing it into the `<iframe>`'s `srcdoc` property.  So far I set it up like this

```
export class ResponsiveWindowComponent {

  @Input() Demonstration!: Type<Component>;

  constructor(
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef
  ){}

  public embedContent(){
    return this.vcRef.createComponent(this.Demonstration).location.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

In my template I do this

```
<section class="resizeFrame">
    <iframe
        class="domFrame"
        sandbox="allow-scripts"
        [srcdoc]="embedContent()"
    ></iframe>
</section>
```

Instead of rendering my component, I only see `[object HTMLElement]` inside of the `<iframe>` and oddly enough it renders the component outside of the iframe multiple times.  [Here's a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz-starters-bzuyxu.stackblitz.io) that shows what I mean.

In the older version of this component I basically do

```
iFrameElement.body.appendChild(this.vcRef.createComponent(this.Demonstration).location.nativeElement);
```

and it works.  The only reason I don't want to continue doing it this way is because it won't work on firefox.  In order to make it work on firefox I need to create another component and add it to my routes and pass it into the `src` value.  I'd prefer not to do this because it loads the entire website into the iframe and navigates to that route so if I had 10 of these iframes on one page my site will be loaded 10 additional times.  What do I need to do to get it to work with the `srcdoc` property?